# Wordpress Form Shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, shortcode

I have created a shortcode for a form in WP. Now I need to make it dynamic and add `<select>` tag with `<options>` for posts and taxonomies.

```
function shortcode_form(){
 $form = "<form method='post'>
             <select name='escape-date' id='escape-date' required>
                  /* NEED TO ADD FUNCTION AND LOGIC TO DISPLAY POSTS */                        
             </select>

             <select name='escape-date' id='escape-date' required>
                  /* NEED TO ADD FUNCTION AND LOGIC TO DISPLAY TAXONOMIES ASSOCIATED WITH SELECTED POST ABOVE */                        
             </select>
          </form>";

 return $form;

}
```

There are two issues:

1 - $form is a `string` so I cannot add functions inside it. Which options do I have?

2 - Change the second `<select>`. Would this only be possible with JS?

Comment: Explain more what "Change the second <select>" means

Comment: The second <select> will be a list of a taxonomy of the post selected above.

Comment: Are you sure you need "taxonomies", or there is a chance you probably need terms instead?
If you need to find out a difference between terms and taxonomies check there https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/158206/is-there-a-difference-between-taxonomies-and-categories

Answer (score 0):

You can populate `<select>` with a list of posts using something like this:

```
/** @var wpdb $wpdb */
global $wpdb;
$posts = query_posts(['post_type' => 'post', 'nopaging' => true]);
$posts_options_tags = array_map( function ( $post ) {
    return "<option value='{$post->ID}'>{$post->post_title}</option>";
}, $posts );
$posts_options_tags = implode('', $posts_options_tags);

$form = "<form method='post'>
         <select name='post_id' id='post_id' required>
            <option>Select a post</option>
            $posts_options_tags                        
         </select>

         <select name='escape-date' id='escape-date' required>
              /* NEED TO ADD FUNCTION AND LOGIC TO DISPLAY TAXONOMIES ASSOCIATED WITH SELECTED POST ABOVE */                        
         </select>
      </form>";
```